# Is it possible to call 2nd tier prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object (1) that is inherited from another object (2).

Both objects in their prototype have an `_init` function. Inside object 1, I would like to call object 2 _init function.

Obviously calling it like `this._init()` will call the first one it finds in the prototype chain which would be object 1's `_init`, is there a way to bypass the first match and make it call the second `_init` which would be object 2s?

Thanks

Comment: Give it a different name...

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It will allow you to bypass the first match and call the second...

Comment: It won't enable me to bypass the first match, it will only make a viable reference to it available, thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say.  This may work for you:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this)._init();
```

**EDIT**: In this case, the following is needed because object 2 is actually the grandparent of object 1:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))._init();
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. He's not wanting to call obj1's _init from obj2, but rather obj2's _init from obj1.

Comment: He says: "Inside object 1, I would like to call object 2 _init function." and says "object (1) ... is inherited from another object (2)."  Assuming `this` is object1, that's what will happen.

Comment: @sh0ber This does work, but as both objects have an _init function in their prototype you have to do, 'Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))._init()`, please update your answer and I will accept, thank you for this.

Comment: @user2251919 You should need two calls only if object 2 is the grandparent of object 1, rather than the parent.  Maybe that is the case in your code. I've updated my answer to show that.